# dot is not working in webpack dev server url after refresh

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have following url:

```
about/myfile.php?..
```

It's working fine when I am coming to the page `myfile.php`. Now, I am refreshing my page. After refresh I am getting:

> Cannot GET /about/myfile.php

As suggested here https://github.com/fabric8-ui/fabric8-ui/pull/1391/files, I have made changes in my webpack.config.js file:

```
 devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: {
        disableDotRule: true,
      },
    },
```

But, it's not working on refresh.